# How to change icon for a custom accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

We created a custom accordion library that will toggle the `.content` element based on what is clicked similar to jQuery accordion. Next to the `.header` element we are displaying a [fontawesome plus icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/plus?style=solid). I am running into issues where the content will hide and show, but the icon will not switch.

**How can i get the content element and icons to switch?**

Current issue:

[image: issue]

Desired output:

[image: desired]

```js
$(function() {
    $('.header').on('click', function() {
      
      var hdr = $(this);
      var grandParents = hdr.parent().parent();
      grandParents.find('.item.active').removeClass('active');
      grandParents.find('.content').stop().slideUp().removeClass('active');
      hdr.closest('.item').find('.content').stop().slideToggle();
      hdr.parent().toggleClass('active');
      
    });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.item.active > .content {
  display: block;
}

.item.active > .header {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.header {
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 8px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="item">
    <h3 class="header">
     <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
     <span>First link</span>
    </h3>
  <div class='content'>  SOME CONTENT HERE </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3 class="header">
     <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
     <span>second link</span>
    </h3>
  <div class='content'>  SOME CONTENT HERE </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <h3 class="header">
     <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
     <span>third link</span>
    </h3>
  <div class='content'>  Some more content </div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: based on provided example you also have svg element inside `header` tag. I pretty sure that this can be fixed in multiple ways. The easiest way would be update header childs based on item status(active or not). Also you can try to move svg into css styles and show differenct background-image based on item status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your js code, please check. The general concept of my update is, in every click, the icon is removed and replaced with a new but different one (from plus to minus and vice versa).

The problem on this is that the use of fontawesome icons. But anyways, take a look on my code.

Here's the full working code. The only update I have is the js part.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.header').on('click', function() {
      var hdr = $(this);
      
      hdr.siblings('.content').slideToggle();
      hdr.parent().toggleClass('active');
      hdr.parent().siblings().find('.content').slideUp();
      hdr.parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
      
      if(hdr.parent().hasClass('active')) {
        hdr.parent().find('svg').remove();
        hdr.parent().siblings().find('svg').remove();
        hdr.prepend('<i class="fas fa-minus"></i>');
        hdr.parent().siblings().find('.header').prepend('<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>');
      } else {
        hdr.parent().find('svg').remove();
        hdr.prepend('<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.item.active > .content {
  display: block;
}

.item.active > .header {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.header {
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 8px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="item">
    <h3 class="header">
     <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
     <span>First link</span>
    </h3>
  <div class='content'>  SOME CONTENT HERE </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3 class="header">
     <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
     <span>second link</span>
    </h3>
  <div class='content'>  SOME CONTENT HERE </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <h3 class="header">
     <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
     <span>third link</span>
    </h3>
  <div class='content'>  Some more content </div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer lead to my eventual solution. Rather then removing the svg, i found out with `Fontawesome` if you change the `data-icon` attribute it changes the icon. So i changed `minus` to `plus` and `plus` to `minus` inside of the `if-else` you have.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

We had same kind of requirement, where we had to replace the + icon of each accordion item with dynamic icon specific to the accordion content, like
1st Accordion - a.png
2nd accordion - b.png and so on.

I did it by adding an image to the Accordion Item page content template and assign it to the cloned accordion rendering.